# Couldn't find ProjectSession with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Here i have a project to which i am adding a session and for a project session i am trying to add task. 
i am able to create project and add project session for project but when i am trying to add task for session using `project_sessions_id` i am getting error `Couldn't find ProjectSession with 'id'=` and `'app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:60:in set_project_session` i am able to get the project session id also `project_sessions/11` in the url but when i click 'create task' i am getting this error. how can i resolve this?

here's what i have done

ProjectSessionController:

```
class ProjectSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_project

  def index
    @project_sessions = ProjectSession.all
  end

  def show
    @project_sessions = ProjectSession.where(project_id: @project.id).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @project_session = ProjectSession.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @project_session = ProjectSession.new(project_session_params)
    @project_session.project_id = @project.id

    #respond_to do |format|
      if @project_session.save
        redirect_to @project
        #format.html { redirect_to @project_session, notice: 'Project session was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project_session }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project_session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    #end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_session.update(project_session_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_session, notice: 'Project session was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project_session }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project_session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @project_session.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_sessions_url, notice: 'Project session was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project_session
      @project_session = ProjectSession.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_session_params
      params.require(:project_session).permit(:session_date, :session_name, :session_description, :start_time, :end_time)
    end
end
```

Task controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_project_session

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.session_id = @project_session.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        redirect_to @project_session
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_project_session
      @project_session = ProjectSession.find(params[:project_session_id])
    end

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

routes:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'hr_dashboard/index'
      resources :roles
      resources :project_sessions
      devise_for :users
      resources :tasks
      resources :projects do
        resources :project_sessions, except: [:show, :index]
      end
      resources :project_sessions do

    resources :tasks, except: [:show, :index]
  end
  authenticated :user do
    root 'admindashboard#index', as:"authenticated_root"
  end  
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'userdashboard/index'
  get 'admindashboard/index'
  get 'welcome/index'
end
```

View for creating new task

```
<div class="container">
<h1>New Task</h1>


<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Back', tasks_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your routes

Comment: @j-dexx i have updated the post with routes..

Comment: Ok, so your routes are nested, can you provide the view code for the link please.

Comment: @j-dexx i have added view.

Answer (score 1):

In your create action of Task controller, you have to add:

```
@task= @project_session.tasks.build(task_params)
```

Because right now, you're not telling the task, to build from the project_session (or with respect to the project_session) you're just telling it to create a new task.

```
@task = Task.new
```

And in the routes.rb file, you've prepared for that to happen by nesting the resources, so it's currently looking for the  **ID** of a **task** that `belongs_to` **project_session.** But can't find any.

And also, in your `form_for` element when creating a ProjectSssion you have let that form know which route it should belong to - I guess you could say - since you still have the un-nested resources available:

```
resources :tasks
```

If project_sessions shouldn't be creatable without a parent, there's no reasons for keeping that, so you should just remove it.

Anyways, here's what the form_for should look like:

```
<%= form_for([@project_session, @task]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: A task belongs to a project session, you've explained what to do if project sessions belonged to a task.

Comment: I updated my answer for future reference. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I had forgotten to add `@project_session` in

```
<%= form_for([@project_session, @task]) do |f| %>
```

just added that and it worked.